# How to divert the traffic to targer servers without port number in URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have 4 web servers, These web servers hosts nearly 8 different websites.
I am planning to use path based routing like http://myexample.com/website1/..

For example when i deployed by application on port 8580 and create the path based rule in ALB.. and hit the url it is not working. Instead i had to use http://myexample.com:8580/website1.

Please help to resolve this, how can i remove the port number from URL.

Since all these are internal application under single domain. I do not have an option of using different domain names or different load balances.

Comment: can you show the routing rule? or `http://myexample.com` I am wonder this is pointing to instance IP not to LB endpoint?

Comment: Sorry i missed up something earlier. Now i followed your suggestion and things are working.. One more query.. So if i want o forward traffic to anyother port..like 8180 or 8280.. I should just add the target group as 8180 or 8280 and then at listner in port 80 i should forward?

Comment: yes you just need to add target group, listener will remain same . just go the rule and add rule against new target group

Comment: Hey Adiii -- I have configured 5 different website by the same approach. But the traffic is been forwarded to default 80 port.

Comment: all on same on the instance?

Comment: If there all one instance then you need nginxin, if they are on different then you ALB host based routing. you need 5 different target group too.

Comment: BTw you should better ask another question, the current answer well as per your question

Comment: Yes all on the same target group i mean two servers

Comment: You should not put in same target group, that is why ALB forward to traffic to single target group.

Comment: this was my intended question from beginning earlier, i did not build all the five servers, So now i have did it and verified, it failed. since i used all the suggestion from here..

Comment: Create 5 different target group with port, then go ALB and add host based routing.

Comment: the servers are same, and 5 websites has five target groups registered on 5 different ports

Comment: See to be more clear.. Target group 1 registered on 8180 and so on till 8480 and from listener on port 80 is forwarded to this target groups

Comment: still fine create five different target and add the server port. LB port will remain same. updatng answer

Comment: I already have 5 different target group but it is going to default route

Comment: the reason is you did not define host-based routing.

Comment: can add screen shot of your listener?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Please see this https://pasteboard.co/IxWAelD.png

Comment: yes make sense, if you defined correct port and target is healhty it should work

Comment: Yes, target are healthy.. if i browse ip:port/path/ they are working fine..re-verified the target.. they seems correct

Comment: and what about lb?

Comment: When i use lb:port/path - not working.... since all the listeners are on port 80.. If i add new listeners for 8180  then LB:8180/path/ is working.. But i dont need Port number in the URL

Comment: You should don't define multiple lister

Comment: One listeners port 80 and then forward to instances port

Comment: I have only one listener, you already saw my pic. I was explaining you if i use multiple listener .. then LB need port in the URL..

Comment: Okay you miss with target group, for each you should expose the app port and path should be exist in application

Comment: Sorry  I did not understand it..

Comment: let discuss in chat

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your load balancer listening on the same port which is used in the webserver.

You need to define a listener for LB to listen on a port and forward traffic to target on the desired group.

specify port `8580` in the target group and specify `80` in the Loadbalancer listener.

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

If all application running on the same instance you need [host-based](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/) routing.

[image]

In the above screenshot, suppose behind each target group there is one instance, but five different target group so `api.example.com` will route to its own target group.

Comment: i think you will not get to this screen now.. Because when i click on insert rule, You will not have a option for this screen.. Can you let us know where to get this rule